# Different results for same test data with trained model

Tags: python, machine-learning, tf-idf, ensemble-learning, tfidfvectorizer

We have loaded trained model using joblib in python and test set of different sizes were given as input for prediction. For eg. we named test set as S1,S2 where S1 has 100 instances and S2 has 1000 instances. The instance 'X' is part of both S1 and S2 which is predicted differently when tested with trained model. We have applied TF-IDF algorithm on dataset to obtain feature vector. The TF-IDF vectorizer vocabulary of trained model is saved as pickle file which is further used to transform the testing data. It would be of great help if anyone could suggest or give solution to the problem.

Actual:
X belongs to class C1

Predicted result:
X belongs to C1 w.r.t S1; 
 X belongs to C2 w.r.t S2

Answer (score 0):

You need to use following function.

```
   random.seed() #or below if you are splitting
   X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.1, stratify = Y, random_state=1) 
   # here random_state=1 makes sure you get same results every time
```

random_state as the name suggests, is used for initializing the internal random number generator, which will decide the splitting of data into train and test indices in your case. In the documentation, it is stated that:

Since you did not provide much information, here is a link for you

[reproducible-results-neural-networks-keras](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reproducible-results-neural-networks-keras/)

Added a example for random.seed()

```
import random
random.seed( 3 )
print "Random number with seed 3 : ", random.random() #will generate 
a random number 
#if you want to use the same random number once again in your program
random.seed( 3 )
random.random()   # same random number as before
```